# Is there a method to refresh data when close v-dialog? (vuetify)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I will try to be concise. I have a table created with vuetify-table, for each item I want to display informations according with their ID in a dialog. For this I've created reservation, reservation_invoice and reservation_rooms like that:

```
reservation : {
    cancellations       : [],
    payment_term        : [],
    departure_city      : '',
    departure_date      : '',
    payment_mode        : '',
    payment_type        : '',
    total               : '',
    nr_room             : '',
    trip                : '',
    response_code       : '',
},
```

Every item is populated from API.

Problem: Everything works well since I've got some reservation without "reservation_invoice" and when I open dialog, in "Reservation Invoice" section it displays the data from the last opened reservation.

Is there a method to refresh reservation, reservation_invoice and reservation_rooms when the modal is closed?

https://codepen.io/alexbucur-dev/pen/YzvdMYN  Here you can find my entire code for this. Maybe the solution is very simple but I have been working with vue for only 2 weeks and I haven't found a solution for this in two days

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method on `click outside` event
eg: your onCloseDialog method will be called and in this method, you can close the dialog and also can get the latest data

```
<v-dialog @click:outside="onCloseDialog" ...
```